# Easy way to convert Qtable obtained from qpython to a formatted string

Tags: python, data-conversion, kdb, qpython

Hi I am both new to python and q/KDB. I am using qpython to get results from a kdb database doing the following:

```
q = qconnection.QConnection(host=self.host, port=self.port, username=self.username, password=self.password)
results = q.sync(query)
```

The result is a qtable. I need to convert the qtable into a string which is straight forward. I just need to do this:

```
resultString = str(results)
```

However the string is somewhat convoluted. Not to say that the table contains  dates and they come in a numeric format.  resultsString look like this:

```
[(6606, b'XX', b'5Y', 26.67, 0.023, 4.833, -22.88, 0.4, b'sx, 570869003211035000)

 (6607, b'XX', b'5Y', 28.40, 0.025, 4.824, -22.75, 0.4, b'sx, 571128191858653000)]
```

I would like to know if there is a straightforward conversion of the qtable to turn the string into something like this:

```
2018-02-01,XX,5Y,26.67,0.023,4.83,-22.88,0.4,sx,2018-02-02D06:43:23\n

2018-02-02,XX,5Y,28.40,0.025,4.82,-22.75,0.4,sx,2018-02-05D06:43:11\n
```

Comment: can you please add the `query` string you are passing in `sync` function ?

Answer (score 2):

You might just want to string the table on the way out from kdb rather than in python. It'll get you what you want but the data won't be easy or efficient to deal with on the python side

```
q)csv 0: select from t
"col1,col2"
"a,1"
"b,2"
"c,3"
```

Try issuing `q.sync("csv 0: select from t")`

Answer (score -1):

Converting the numerical columns to `string` can achieve the results you are after.

```
results = q.sync('t:([] 2?.z.d;2?.z.t;2?`3;p:2?100.);update string d, string t, string p from t')

for item in results:
     t = ()
     for x in item:
         t = t + (x.decode(),)     
     print(t)

('2017.05.31', '16:46:10.161', 'jgj', '43.9081')
('2006.09.28', '19:44:11.560', 'cfl', '57.59051')
```